# Problems using my black garlic fermenter

Tags: equipment, garlic

I just got my fermenter and my garlic came out hard and dried.  It also tastes bitter.

The machine I have is Homend 5L Black Garlic Fermenter Full Automatic Intelligent Control Garlics Maker Multiple Clove Garlic DIY Cooker.

Just wondering if anyone else has used a fermeter and has had this problem also.

Answer (score 2):

Try it for just 7 or 8 days instead of 12. Some machines let you adjust the time starting at 7 days because for the garlic available in North America, 12 days is too long.

Answer (score 0):

Changes in humidity and changes in the garlic supply throughout the year mean that no single recipe is going to yield the same results every time.  Each run must be checked daily starting at day 7.

The hard, bitter black garlic can be used, too.  Grind and sift it for sprinkling on light colored dishes or adding to sauces or cooking greens.

Suggestions for a few things to do differently from the box instructions:

- completely peeling all cloves before instead of after curing makes it much easier to actually use the garlic when cooking and no flavor is lost in the discarded peels
- cloves all go into a plastic or semi-sealed foil bag to keep more moisture in
- remove the batch when it has the flavor you want, and tune the texture and moisture later
- partially drying the cured garlic in a dedicated dehydrator instead of in the black garlic machine frees up the machine for the next batch